# Call service from existing api gateway using base path mappings

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Our API has the following endpoints:

```
POST /users - create a user
GET /users/{userId} - get a particular user

GET /posts/{postId} - get a particular post
GET /posts/{postId}/users - get the users who contributed to this post
```

I have defined two services: users-service and posts-service. In these two services I define the lambdas like so. I'm using the `serverless-domain-manager` plugin to create base path mappings:

/users-service/serverless.yaml:

```
service: users-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: 'serverlesstesting.example.com'
    basePath: 'users'
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true

functions:
  create:
    name: userCreate
    handler: src/create.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
  get:
    name: userGet
    handler: src/get.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{userId}
          method: get
```

/rooms-service/serverless.yaml:

```
service: posts-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: 'serverlesstesting.example.com'
    basePath: 'posts'
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true

functions:
  get:
    name: postsGet
    handler: src/get.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{postId}
          method: get
getUsersForPost:
    handler: userGet ? 
    events: ??
```

The problem is that the `GET /posts/{postId}/users` actually calls the same `userGet` lambda from the `users-service`. But the source for that lambda lives in the users-service, not the posts-service.

So my question becomes:
How do I reference a service from another service using base path mappings? In other words, is it possible for the posts service to actually make a call to the parent custom domain and into the users base path mapping and its service?

Answer (score 0):

Consider or refer below approach 
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/share-an-api-endpoint-between-services.html